# How am I supposed to darken the entire background of my body?

Tags: css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-overlay {
  background: rgba(72, 70, 82, 0.5);
}

body {
  color: white;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: url("images/friends.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<wrapper-overlay>

  <body>
  </body>
</wrapper-overlay>

</html>
```

I made the background so that it is 100% of its parent element, but the background:rgba does not darken the bottom part of the background. I tried putting the background in the html css but it did not work either.

Comment: What's `<wrapper-overlay>`?

Answer (score 1):

I understand you would like to apply a dark background to the entire page.
It looks like you should use the min-height property. Here is the basic logic to use:

```
<style>
    html,body{
        height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
    }
    body{
        background:rgba(72, 70, 82, 0.5);
    }
</style>

<html>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-overlay {
  background: rgba(72, 70, 82, 0.5);
}

body {
  color: white;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: url("images/friends.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="wrapper-overlay">

  <body>
  </body>
</div>

</html>
```

Your error is the wrapper-overlay it should be a div with that class.

Comment: it should simply be a block element .. and we should never wrap body element like this